# Angular ng-model ng-repeat clear all input

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

Why function `clear()` doesn't work in this example below ?

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
    <div class="form-control" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:number">
      <input type="text" ng-model="newVar" />
      <span>{{newVar}}</span>
    </div>
    <!-- //form controll -->
    <input type="range" ng-model="number" max="9" />
    <label>Repeat input fields {{number}} times</label>
    <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Controller**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
    $scope.number = 5;
    $scope.newVar = 0;
    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.newVar ='';
    }
});//AppController

app.filter('range', function () {
  return function (input, total) {
    total = parseInt(total);
    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  }; //filter range
});
```

here is my **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2HWpGjKQfU4DaMWakPFO?p=preview)**

Comment: What is clear() meant to do?

Comment: i can see clear erasing all the inputs values...

Comment: Yes, clear() must be delete all value from inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-repeat` creates a child scope for every 'repeat', so you can access the controller's scope by using `$parent`. In addition, you can use an array/object to store all values and not use just one variable for all the different lines in the view. You can do this using `$index` inside `ng-repeat`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
    <div class="form-control" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:number">
      <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.newVar[$index]" />
      <span>{{newVar[$index]}}</span>
    </div>
    <!-- //form controll -->
    <input type="range" ng-model="number" max="9" />
    <label>Repeat input fields {{number}} times</label>
    <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This way `clear()` cleans all the values because it sets the whole object to an empty string.

That is why I would also change the clear function to something like this:

```
$scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.newVar = {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks! ng-model="$parent.newVar[$index]" it's all what I need

Answer (score 0):

When you update the textbox value manually it actually sets the `newVar` value in **childScope** (created by ng-repeat directive) so instead of binding it to the newVar try to bind the value with `$parent.newVar` and it would work perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
    <div class="form-control" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:number">
      <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.newVar" />
      <span>{{newVar}}</span>
    </div>
    <!-- //form controll -->
    <input type="range" ng-model="number" max="9" />
    <label>Repeat input fields {{number}} times</label>
    <button ng-click="clear()">clear</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhKm4yp0VtDefwooVcI4?p=preview) is the plunk for you

Comment: As a side note you are binding one single variable to all the textbox so it would update values at all the textboxes and span tag.

Comment: clear() is working, but after use it scope is broken. All inputs type the same data

Comment: @andrzej That's what I have mentioned in comment.